# Copy object array into another

Tags: arrays, vba, class

I have trouble copy a object array into another one of the same type. I receive a 438 error ("Object Doesn’t Support this Property or Method Error"). I don't understand why.

The facture class

```
Public clientName As String
Public realisationDate As Date

Property Get factureDate () As Date
factureDate = Now
End Property
```

The sub :

```
Dim firstArray() As New Facture
ReDim firstArray(arSize) 'the size is defined elsewere and work perfectly

Dim secondArray() As New Facture

...

lineSecondArray = lineSecondArray + 1
ReDim secondArray(lineSecondArray)
secondArray(lineSecondArray) = firstArray(lineFirstArray)
```

Any help would be highy appreciated.

Comment: What is `Fracture`? Did you try to `Set` it? `Set secondArray(lineSecondArray) = firstArray(lineFirstArray)`

Comment: "Fracture" is nothing. "Facture" is my Class. And... No but now that you pointed it, it was the problem. I feel supid not having thinked to something so simple before. Thank you !